# Export Outlook Emails (Mac) to Gmail

Tags: macos, ms-office, gmail, import

I'm looking to export emails from Outlook and Entourage from Macs, and import them into Gmail (Google Apps).

Any suggestions? Found really simple solutions for Mac Mail and Outlook for Windows, but nothing for Outlook on a Mac.

Alternatively, is there any way to export Outlook emails (Mac) to either Mac Mail or Outlook for Windows? Then, I could upload to Gmail from there (risk loosing email quality, attachments, etc.)

Comment: What happen if your IMAP is disabled in your GMAIL?

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the setup you already have, but I think this should work.

- In your mail client (Entourage/ Outlook) setup the [IMAP](http://www.office.mvps.org/accounts/imap.html) access to your Gmail account.
- Setup the folders for sent and trash.
- Move all mails from your other inboxes to your Gmail inbox:
  Select all folders by clicking the top one under the account to be moved, and then <kbd>Shift</kbd>-click the bottom one. After all the folders are selected, drag and then drop them onto your Gmail account in the sidebar. (If there are many folders you may want to consider testing a couple first, before moving all of them).

If the account is large, it will take awhile to upload all the email.

Comment: This is correct. I have performed this at least twice for very large email accounts (many emails, and many folders). It works flawlessly, and is simple.

Comment: This is awesome! I got them connected successfully - thank you! However, I'm not able to find the Gmail folder, to drag everything into? Any idea why this wasn't created? Tried on two different computers- neither of them are showing them.

Comment: @Joseph : I don't have a version of entourage or outlook to test but you might have to add a new "mailbox" (folder) hosted on the gmail account and then move / copy all your folders to that mailbox and reorder everything on gmail afterwards.

Comment: If I want to do this same thing but I no longer have access to my Outlook account, can it be done? I do have an Outlook for Mac archive/database of all the emails I want to transfer. I also have an Apple Mail archive too. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that you need to create a new gmail account in Outlook to shift the files to. I have done this (finally) but can't work out how to shift the files into the new folder or account. Drag & drop doesn't seem to work